# Use `dispatch` hook in UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to `dispatch` some action when my React component unmounts. As I am using hooks, I can't use `componentWillUnmount`. Instead, I am using the `useEffect` hook:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => () => dispatch(setValue()), []);
```

Above code throws the warning "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array". I can't include `dispatch` in dependencies array as it will cause `useEffect` to run whenever `dispatch` changes, but I want it to run only when the component is unmounting; and for that I need to pass an empty array.

How can I fix this warning without removing the corresponding linting rule from babel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook/55854902#55854902)

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch` should not change, it's the dispatch function provided from the redux store. The react hook linter just sees it as a function, however, and is warning you it *can* be mutated. I think you've a syntax error though, missing parens. I think it should be

```
useEffect(() => () => dispatch(setValue()), []);
```

You can ignore the rule for that line though, if necessary

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Usage

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
useEffect(() => () => dispatch(setValue()), []);
```

or (IMO a bit easier to read)

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => dispatch(setValue());
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```